# JPanel , BoxLayout Alignment

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

Can you tell me the best way to get the button panel under the other 2 panels?  Using a FLowLayout for the JFrame and BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS for the 3 panels (leftPanel, rightPanel, and buttonPanel)

[image]

Thanks I appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another panels and mix layouts. I would do this way:

Create a `JPanel` (I will call this `panel0`) with `BoxLayout` with `PAGE_AXIS`. Set this as the content pane of `JFrame`.

Create another `JPanel` with `FlowLayout` (`panel1`) and add the panels with the labels and text fields to `panel1`. Add `panel1` to `panel0`.

Add the panel with the buttons to `panel0`.

Comment: How would I set this as the content view of JFrame?

Comment: Sorry, it is content pane. `JFrame.setContentPane(Container)`.

Comment: When you use this setContentPane(containerPanel);   Do you still do add(containerPanel);  ??